# Move files from Azure storage to a local directory

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files

I want to move all the files that in a File share on azure. I can do it at the moment by following way using:

1. Use "net" command to connect to the network drive and assign it a drive letter
2. Then there's a bat file that uses "move" command like `move g:\files\* c:\files` to then move the files which runs every hour to check if there are files and move them using windows task scheduler.

But I don't want to use this way because:

1. The drive will be disconnected if the Machine needs a restart and hence the process doesn't remain automated as someone will have to mount the drive again
2. The "move" command doesn't moves folders, it moves only files.

Is there a better way of managing this? We don't want to install tools like AzCopy but using Powershell is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved using the following approach:

1. Delete any existing mapped drive to the drive letter we are using with the `net use <drive_letter> /delete` command. This is done to make sure the drive was detached since the last time script ran
2. Map the drive again using the `net use` command
3. Copy all the files using `robocopy`
4. After that delete all the files using `del` command
5. Disconnect the drive now using the `net use <drive_letter> /delete` command

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you can do it as the following ways:

1.Call Azcopy in PowerShell.

You could install Azcopy firstly, you could download the latest version from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#download-and-install-azcopy). Azcopy supports upload directory to Azure fileshare. You could use the following command.

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ /DestKey:key /S
```

Then you could write a bat script to call Azcopy, by default Azure install directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy`.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"
&.\AzCopy.exe /Source:C:\myfolder /Dest:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ /DestKey:key /S
```

2. Use PowerShell Script, you could use to this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Recursively-upload-a-bfb615fe). The script use for ASM mode, you should change some command.

Based on my experience, using Azcopy is more easily and simpler.

Comment: Hi Walter, I want to move files from azure storage to my computer, not copy them. How can I do that?

Comment: The azcopy command I provided is upload file to azure storage account. You could check the first link, you also could download file from azure storage account to your local PC. Move? do you mean download, then delete it? Azcopy does not support this, you should doanload, then delete them.

Comment: Hi Walter, yes download and delete them. Can you please update it whenever you can?

Comment: @GurvinderSingh Azcopy does not support delete a file on FIleShare, I suggest you could use Azcopy to download file from Azure Fileshare. Then use PowerShell cmdlet `Remove-AzureStorageDirectory –Share $s –Path Images` to delete them. More information please refer to this [link](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/azure-files-how-to-manage-shares-directories-and-files/).

Comment: @GurvinderSingh You also could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to manage Azure Fileshare, but it could not move your file automation.